# How to get CPU usage in MySQL per user?

Tags: mysql, monitoring, cpu

I want to know is there anyway to get CPU usage per user in MySQL? for example I have 3 different users 'user1', 'user2' and 'user3'. I want to get the average/real time memory usage and CPU usage of these users.I googled a lot but I did not find any suitable tool. Maybe I can get these data from MySQL queries, but I don't know where are they stored.

Answer (score 3):

- Some resource *limitations*: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-resources.html and https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/grant/#resource-limit-options
- Switch to MariaDB to get "user stats" (connections, bytes, rows, CPU, etc): https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/information-schema-user_statistics-table/ and  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/user-statistics/

Comment: its show CPU_TIME but i want to have CPU usage in Percentage or Frequency.

Comment: @behnambahadori - Does it give enough raw data such that you can compute Percentage or Frequency?

Comment: I want to know how can i use raw data to getting CPU usage in Precentage, now i don't have any idea for this issue...

Comment: I know how I can get the CPU usage in time (top, ps, user_statistics,...). I want to know is there anyway to convert the %CPU time to cpu core?
I run top for 5 seconds after 5 seconds I get 30% for %CPU from top which is 1.5 seconds. and mysql shows 60% within the 5 seconds which means 0.9 seconds is for mysql. Now how can I convert this value to cpu core? for example mysql used 1.2 cores during a 5 secind period